# How to explode (un-nest) a nested Data Frame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nested

I have a pandas `DataFrame` with a nested `DataFrame` in one column, I want to explode the nested column but cannot figure out how to achieve this, I've read some posts about how to un-nest `list` objects, but seems to not be working with the pandas dataframe, I have the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[datetime(2020,1,2), 334, pd.DataFrame(
                                                [[datetime(2020,1,3), 555],
                                                [datetime(2020,1,4), 678]],
                                                columns=['date', 'value'],
                                                index=['Italy']*2
                                            )], 
                  [datetime(2020,1,3), 332, pd.DataFrame(
                                                [[datetime(2020,1,3), 555],
                                                [datetime(2020,1,4), 678]],
                                                  columns=['date', 'value'],
                                                  index=['US']*2
                                            )],
                  [datetime(2020,1,4), 115, pd.DataFrame(
                                                [[datetime(2020,1,3), 555],
                                                [datetime(2020,1,4), 678]],
                                                  columns=['date', 'value'],
                                                  index=['Germany']*2
                                            )]
                  ],
                 columns=['date', 'value', 'nested_values'],
                 index=['Italy', 'US', 'Germany'])
```

The expected result should be something like this:

```
+--------+------------+-----+
+Italy   + 2020-01-02 + 334 +
+Italy   + 2020-01-03 + 555 +
+Italy   + 2020-01-04 + 678 +
+US      + 2020-01-03 + 332 +
+US      + 2020-01-03 + 555 +
+US      + 2020-01-04 + 678 +
+Germany + 2020-01-04 + 115 +
+Germany + 2020-01-03 + 555 +
+Germany + 2020-01-04 + 678 +
+--------+------------+-----+
```

Comment: Are you trying to explode a column of DataFrames? That's pretty bizarre as a requirement. But it should be easy enough with `df = df.drop('nested_values',1).append(pd.concat(df['nested_values'].tolist())).sort_index()`

Comment: how did you end up with a nested pandas dataframe?

Comment: I'm not sure how I ended up with this nested df but with the @cs95 answer I could flat my data. Thank you.